How can I move all files that match a glob into a folder using processResources?
Simply, I need to move all files within resources into a packed folder during the processResources step that matches the assets/*/fog_definitions/**/*.json glob.
Originally, I tried to do this:
task moveFogDefinitions(type: Copy) {
    from fileTree('src/main/resources/assets') {
        include '*/fog_definitions/**/*.json'
    }
    into file('build/packed')
}

processResources.dependsOn moveFogDefinitions

However this doesn't work. How do I do this correctly?
